# Angular 2 provider is not accessible in components

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services

I am new on angular 2. I was following the legacy quick-start application, Tour of Heroes.

I created services as mentioned in the application.

I have a service HeroService. Which is used to pull all the heroes data.

I have included the HeroService at the app.module file as provider to be able to access it through out the application for all application.

My app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent }  from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroesComponent }  from './heroes.component';
import { HeroService }  from './hero.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'heroes',
        component: HeroesComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HeroesComponent, HeroDetailComponent ],
  providers: [ HeroService ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And my Component File where I want to Access the HeroService to get data is:

```
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }
}
```

The problem is I am getting an error like this, when i build the project :

> Cannot find name 'HeroService'.

I have followed all the steps correctly. If I import the HeroService in my HeroesComponent, it seems to work. But fails when not imported.
Am I missing some step. As far as I understood declaring the provider on app.module will register it to use throughout the application/components without need of importing it each time.

Please correct me If I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: Have you imported `HeroService` in your component file ?

Comment: did you exported `HeroService` class from `hero.service.ts` file?

Comment: No I didn't that was my query, If I need to import it again, as I already added it as provider in app.module. Thought we can do without importing it. Now I don't see a point in adding it as a provider in app.module as we have to every time import it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import inside the component as well

```
import { HeroService }  from './hero.service';
```

Comment: So we need to import it even if we have added in the app.module providers ?

Comment: I thought no need as we have already defined it in app.module as provider. Thanks for the prompt answer. I imported earlier, but was confused if we can avoid the import. Now I don't see a point in including it in app.module as provider, as we have to import it every time. Just we can avoid a provider key in Component Decorator. Or I am not able to see the big picture behind it.